# C# project update MySQL list of rows selected from two tables

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I have a project updating Magento store *priselist*. I have list of items which I want to update and I want to do it with one MySQL query (by thinking, that it's more efficient). The *priselist* include sku and price.

I have this two tables. From ***table 1*** I use ***sku*** to update in ***table 2*** the ***value***, which is the price of the item when ***entity_id*** are equal in both tables and attribute_id is '64'.

table 1

```
product_entity

entity_id  |  sku
        1  |   p1   
        2  |   p2
        3  |   p3
```

table 2

```
product_entity_decimal

entity_id  |  attribute_id  |  value   |
        1  |            64  |      5   |
        1  |            65  |   NULL   |
        1  |            66  |   NULL   |
        2  |            64  |      7   |
        2  |            65  |   NULL   |
        2  |            66  |   NULL   |
        3  |            64  |      1   |
        3  |            65  |   NULL   |
        3  |            66  |   NULL   |
```

So, how can I update with one query p1 prise to be 6 and p3 prise to be 2.

I try this query but it didn't work...

```
UPDATE product_entity, product_entity_decimal SET product_entity_decimal.value =
CASE 
    WHEN product_entity.entity_id = product_entity_decimal.entity_id AND product_entity_decimal.attribute_id =  '64' AND product_entity.sku =  'p1' THEN '6'
    WHEN product_entity.entity_id = product_entity_decimal.entity_id AND product_entity_decimal.attribute_id =  '64' AND product_entity.sku =  'p1' THEN '2'
    ELSE value
END
```

For my project I'm using C# with .Net and MySQL 5.x by using MySql.Data.MySqlClient. Maybe there is better way to update list of 3000 items in MySQL database if there is share it please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` within `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE product_entity_decimal a
JOIN   product_entity b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id AND b.sku IN ('p1', 'p3')
SET    a.value = CASE b.sku WHEN 'p1' THEN 6 WHEN 'p2' THEN 2 END
WHERE  a.attribute_id = 64
```

---

If you have a list of 3000 items you want to update, perhaps the best way would be to iterate over an array and execute one `UPDATE` per iteration. These updates would be encased within a transaction such as in this pseudo-code:

```
// START TRANSACTION

// For Each Value in array
    // Execute UPDATE statement

// COMMIT
```

Comment: Thank you it was useful, but I have a question. Isn't it require more server side resources to execute multiple SQL queries than the one I was trying for? The purpose of my project is to lighter up the host side. I got to other idea base on "memory = 1/calculation"; this mean that on the exporting data I'll keep entity_id and then it will be simple update in one table, but again one query or multiple, I'm still thinking that one query is better than many.